# How to save and read records in a Delphi tClientDataset

Tags: delphi-xe2, tclientdataset

Good day

I am a Delphi newb. I am trying to programmatically save a record to a tClientDataset and then read the record from the dataset. I think I seem to have managed to successfully save the record in the dataset, because after I appended data to a record and posted it, the recordcount of the dataset is 1. 
However, when I try and read the values of the records, I get Null back.
I created the tclientdataset using the toolbar and manually setting the fields in the design window. the dataset's name is

```
dsUnitData
```

I am using Delphi RadStudio XE2.
Can anyone please help by indicating what I am doing wrong to read Null instead of the earlier populated values?

Here is my code:

```
procedure TfFeetRevenueByUnit.BitBtn1Click(Sender: TObject);
var test, theunitname : string;
count, feet, counter : integer;
revenue :currency;
begin
label3.Visible := false;

dsUnitData.Insert;
dsUnitData.FieldValues['Field_UnitName'] := 'test';
dsUnitData.FieldValues['Field_Feet'] := 10;
dsUnitData.FieldValues['Field_Revenue'] := 10.1;
dsUnitData.Post;

count := dsUnitData.RecordCount;

if not dsUnitData.Active then
dsUnitData.Open;
dsUnitData.First;
while not dsUnitData.EOF do
begin
theunitname := dsUnitData.FieldByName('Field_UnitName').Value;
feet := dsUnitData.FieldByName('Field_UnitName').Value;
revenue := dsUnitData.FieldByName('Field_Revenue').Value;
dsUnitData.Next;
end;
```

Comment: Remove the `while not dsUnitData.Eof` loop and the `dsUnitData.Next`. They're only used  if you're iterating through multiple records, and you're only reading one.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. I did remove the two lines of code, however, I am still getting a Null value at line: theunitname := dsUnitData.FieldByName('Field_UnitName').Value;

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. I had set the FieldKind of the Fields for the tClientDataset wrongly. 
I set the FieldKind as `fkCalculated` but it should have been `fkInternalCalc`.

Comment: Those fields do not appear to be either of those things. They appear to be fkData (data storage of the indicated type). You should really read the documentation.